# plotting a bar using d3 in html

Tags: html, d3.js, plot, bar-chart

I am reading a tutorial on plotting bar chart using d3 in html. Here is a link to the tutorial: [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714).
I have copied the html content in a file called `index.html` and copied the data file in a file called `data.tsv`.

Here are both files:

index.html is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}

</script>
```

and data.stv is:

```
name    value
Locke   4
Reyes   8
Ford    15
Jarrah  16
Shephard    23
Kwon    42
```

but when I open `index.html` in a web-browser I do not see anything.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Your index.html is completely different from the index.html in the example you've linked to.

Comment: sorry yes I corrected it, I still don't see anything when I open the index.html.

Comment: If you are running this locally you need to run a webserver, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

Comment: Thanks Lars. Do I need to install anything? Can you please show me what part of the link that you pointed to I need to read?

Comment: It's under "Installing".

Comment: Lars, I enter `python -m http.server 8888 &` and then when I click on the link to `http://localhost:8888/`, I get this error: `Exception happened during processing of request from ('...my ip', 18287)`.

Comment: if you are having troubles with console installation and such you can try using mamp (for macos) or wamp (for windows). it creates a local server so you can try websites and webpages locally

Comment: @tomtomtom thanks it helped and worked. I installed wamp for windows.